# How to separate and position tkzpicture figures around the page coordinate system

Tags: tikz-pgf

[image]

Hey there! I would like to understand how to apply Latex page coordinate system on tkzpicture figures. I want to correctly position my triangle's center point relative to the x-axis of the circle. Also, I would to anchor the triangle west of the page and the circle to the east of the page.

Here is the my code:

```
\begin{center}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \draw[very thin] (0,0)--(3,0)--(3,2)--cycle;
    
    \coordinate[label=left:$P$](P)  at  (0,0);
    \coordinate[label=right:$Q$](Q)  at  (3,0);
    \coordinate[label=above:$R$](R)  at   (3,2);
    
    \tkzLabelSegment[below=2pt](P,Q){$x$}
    \tkzLabelSegment[right=2pt](Q,R){$y$} 
    \tkzLabelSegment[above left=-6pt](P,R){$\sqrt{x^2+y^2}$}
    
    \tkzMarkAngle[size=0.7](P,R,Q)
    \tkzLabelAngle[pos=1](Q,P,R){$\varphi$}
    \tkzMarkAngle[size=0.8](Q,P,R)
    \tkzLabelAngle[pos=1](P,R,Q){$\psi$}
    \tkzMarkRightAngle(P,Q,R)
\end{tikzpicture}
\qquad
\begin{tikzpicture}[r]
    \draw [thin, gray, ->] (0,-3) -- (0,3)      % draw y-axis line
    node [above, black] {$y$};              % add label for y-axis
    
    \draw [thin, gray, ->] (-3,0) -- (3,0)      % draw x-axis line
    node [right, black] {$x$};              % add label for x-axis
    
    %circle
    \draw[fill=none, very thin](0,0) circle (2.5);
    \draw[fill=black](0,0) node [below left] {$O$};
    
    %dots % their lines
    \draw [dashed] (1.76,0) -- (1.76,1.76) -- (-1.76,1.76);
    \draw [very thin] (0,0) -- (1.76,1.76)  node[circle,black,fill,inner sep=1pt]{} node[above right]{$P_{\varphi}$};
    
    \draw [dashed] (-1.76,0) -- (-1.76,1.76);
    \draw[very  thin] (0,0) -- (-1.76,1.76)  node[circle,black,fill,inner sep=1pt]{} node[above left]{$P_{\frac{\pi}{2}-\varphi}$};
    
    %angles
    \draw (1.1,0) arc (0:135:1.1)node[above left,pos=0.65]{$\frac{\pi}{2}-\varphi$};
    
    \draw (0.5,0) arc (0:45:0.5)node[above right,pos=0.1]{$\varphi$};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{center}
```

Please apply your modification passed on that code provided on a sample paper.

Thank you

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Please always provide a compilable minimal working example.

Comment: Ok. Just help me center the triangle along the circle's x-axis.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't fully understand what exactly you want, but I take it that you want to align the left picture with the left margin of the body text and the right picture with the right margin of the body text. So, maybe what you're after is something like this, which would additionally align both x-axis of the two pictures (`\lipsum` text added to illustrate the alignment with the margins of the body text):

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage{tkz-euclide}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}

\lipsum[1]

\begin{center}
\begin{tikzpicture}[baseline=0pt]
    \draw[very thin] (0,0)--(3,0)--(3,2)--cycle;
    
    \coordinate[label=left:$P$](P)  at  (0,0);
    \coordinate[label=right:$Q$](Q)  at  (3,0);
    \coordinate[label=above:$R$](R)  at   (3,2);
    
    \tkzLabelSegment[below=2pt](P,Q){$x$}
    \tkzLabelSegment[right=2pt](Q,R){$y$} 
    \tkzLabelSegment[above left=-6pt](P,R){$\sqrt{x^2+y^2}$}
    
    \tkzMarkAngle[size=0.7](P,R,Q)
    \tkzLabelAngle[pos=1](Q,P,R){$\varphi$}
    \tkzMarkAngle[size=0.8](Q,P,R)
    \tkzLabelAngle[pos=1](P,R,Q){$\psi$}
    \tkzMarkRightAngle(P,Q,R)
\end{tikzpicture}
\hfill
\begin{tikzpicture}[baseline=0pt]
    \draw [thin, gray, ->] (0,-3) -- (0,3)      % draw y-axis line
    node [above, black] {$y$};              % add label for y-axis
    
    \draw [thin, gray, ->] (-3,0) -- (3,0)      % draw x-axis line
    node [right, black] {$x$};              % add label for x-axis
    
    %circle
    \draw[fill=none, very thin](0,0) circle (2.5);
    \draw[fill=black](0,0) node [below left] {$O$};
    
    %dots % their lines
    \draw [dashed] (1.76,0) -- (1.76,1.76) -- (-1.76,1.76);
    \draw [very thin] (0,0) -- (1.76,1.76)  node[circle,black,fill,inner sep=1pt]{} node[above right]{$P_{\varphi}$};
    
    \draw [dashed] (-1.76,0) -- (-1.76,1.76);
    \draw[very  thin] (0,0) -- (-1.76,1.76)  node[circle,black,fill,inner sep=1pt]{} node[above left]{$P_{\frac{\pi}{2}-\varphi}$};
    
    %angles
    \draw (1.1,0) arc (0:135:1.1)node[above left,pos=0.65]{$\frac{\pi}{2}-\varphi$};
    
    \draw (0.5,0) arc (0:45:0.5)node[above right,pos=0.1]{$\varphi$};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{center}

\lipsum[1]

\end{document}
```

[image]

Or maybe you want to align both pictures vertically centered to each other:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage{tkz-euclide}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}

\lipsum[1]

\begin{center}
\begin{tikzpicture}[baseline=(current bounding box.center)]
    \draw[very thin] (0,0)--(3,0)--(3,2)--cycle;
    
    \coordinate[label=left:$P$](P)  at  (0,0);
    \coordinate[label=right:$Q$](Q)  at  (3,0);
    \coordinate[label=above:$R$](R)  at   (3,2);
    
    \tkzLabelSegment[below=2pt](P,Q){$x$}
    \tkzLabelSegment[right=2pt](Q,R){$y$} 
    \tkzLabelSegment[above left=-6pt](P,R){$\sqrt{x^2+y^2}$}
    
    \tkzMarkAngle[size=0.7](P,R,Q)
    \tkzLabelAngle[pos=1](Q,P,R){$\varphi$}
    \tkzMarkAngle[size=0.8](Q,P,R)
    \tkzLabelAngle[pos=1](P,R,Q){$\psi$}
    \tkzMarkRightAngle(P,Q,R)
\end{tikzpicture}
\hfill
\begin{tikzpicture}[baseline=(current bounding box.center)]
    \draw [thin, gray, ->] (0,-3) -- (0,3)      % draw y-axis line
    node [above, black] {$y$};              % add label for y-axis
    
    \draw [thin, gray, ->] (-3,0) -- (3,0)      % draw x-axis line
    node [right, black] {$x$};              % add label for x-axis
    
    %circle
    \draw[fill=none, very thin](0,0) circle (2.5);
    \draw[fill=black](0,0) node [below left] {$O$};
    
    %dots % their lines
    \draw [dashed] (1.76,0) -- (1.76,1.76) -- (-1.76,1.76);
    \draw [very thin] (0,0) -- (1.76,1.76)  node[circle,black,fill,inner sep=1pt]{} node[above right]{$P_{\varphi}$};
    
    \draw [dashed] (-1.76,0) -- (-1.76,1.76);
    \draw[very  thin] (0,0) -- (-1.76,1.76)  node[circle,black,fill,inner sep=1pt]{} node[above left]{$P_{\frac{\pi}{2}-\varphi}$};
    
    %angles
    \draw (1.1,0) arc (0:135:1.1)node[above left,pos=0.65]{$\frac{\pi}{2}-\varphi$};
    
    \draw (0.5,0) arc (0:45:0.5)node[above right,pos=0.1]{$\varphi$};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{center}

\lipsum[1]

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your help.

Comment: You can also align sepcific coordinates using, for example, `[baseline=(P)]`.